# How to pass a dynamic variable into a JavaScript Shader

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, glsl, vertex-shader

I have created a primitive sphere using THREE.SphereGeometry. I am applying a displacement shader, to give it a bumpy effect. I am trying to animate the scale of the bumps with volume from the microphone. I am unable to pass my volume variable into the shader to affect the scale. I am logging the volume variable and I see that it is appropriately updating from my microphone.

The dynamic variable is:

> var volume = meter.volume * 1000.0;

```
function drawLoop(time) {

rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame(drawLoop);

var volume = meter.volume * 1000.0;

//var volume = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(meter.volume);

javascript: console.log(typeof(volume));


THREE.DisplacementShader = {

    uniforms: {

        texture1: {
            type: "t",
            value: null
        },
        scale: {
            type: "f",
            value: 100 + volume
        },
        volume: {
            type: "f",
            value: meter.volume
        },
    },

    vertexShader: [

        "varying vec2 vUv;",
        "varying float noise;",
        "varying vec3 fNormal;",
        "uniform sampler2D texture1;",
        "uniform float scale;",
        "uniform float time;",
        "varying float volume;",


        "void main() {",

        "vUv = uv;",
        "fNormal = normal;",

        "vec4 noiseTex = texture2D( texture1, vUv );",

        "noise = noiseTex.r + time;",
        //adding the normal scales it outward
        //(normal scale equals sphere diameter)
        "vec3 newPosition = position + normal  * noise * scale * (volume*100.0);",

        "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( newPosition, 1.0 );",

        "}"

    ].join("\n"),

    fragmentShader: [

        "varying vec2 vUv;",
        "varying float noise;",
        "varying vec3 fNormal;",

        "void main( void ) {",

        // compose the colour using the normals then
        // whatever is heightened by the noise is lighter
        "gl_FragColor = vec4( fNormal * noise, 1. );",

        "}"

    ].join("\n")

};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined

```
varying float volume;
```

in your vertex-shader. It should instead read

```
uniform float volume;
```